# Why I get error when try map array in React+Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I try run this :

```
const nums = this.props.date.phoneNumbers.map( (num) => {
      <span>{ num }<br/></span>
})
```

I get err :

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

But all work without span :

```
const nums = this.props.date.phoneNumbers.map( (num) => {
      console.log(num);
})
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `return` to return any value since you opened curly brackets

```
   const nums = this.props.date.phoneNumbers.map( (num) => {
         return <span>{ num }<br/></span>
        })
```